# WPF Control Image fails in WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, image

I am noob in WPF. I have a tab control with an icon on the tabs. When I import it by ElementHost the control in winforms, the icon does not appear on the tab. I load the icon image from Resource.

[image]

XAML Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF_Prueba.TabControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="tabIcon" UriSource="/Resources/delete.png" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TabControl Name="tabDynamic" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button Name="btnDelete" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="Transparent" Margin="5,0,-3,0" Padding="0" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                            <Image Source="{StaticResource tabIcon}" Height="10" Width="10"></Image>
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}, Path=Header}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If anyone can help me please. Sorry for typos.

Best regards.

Comment: I wasn't talking about your English. I said why would you create a control in WPF and try to host it in WinForms? These two are two completely different technologies. Mixing these two NEVER ends up working the way you want it to.

Comment: It is perfectly possible. No matter whether one is WPF and other is Winforms. WPF controls can be used perfectly in Winforms.

Comment: Make sure your `png` file has it's `Build Action` set to `Resource` (Solution Explorer -> file properties).

Comment: @HighCore Thank you very much!!! That was the problem :)

Comment: @SamuelPedrosa don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your `png` file has it's `Build Action` set to `Resource`:

[image]